# WPF navigating between TabItems issue

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I have this DataGrid in TabItem:

```
        <TabControl x:Name="MainTab" FontSize="12" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="MainTab_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem x:Name="tabAddDocs" Header=Add Docs"></TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabEmpList" Header="Employee List">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="empGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                  SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFCDCDCD" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="empGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
                  FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="empGrid_MouseDoubleClick" 
                  Loaded="empGrid_Loaded" Focusable="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btnJump" Click="btnJump_Click">Jump</Button>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I want that when i double click on the DataGrid the other tab will be shown, so i used this method:

```
private void empGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tabAddDocs.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

But nothing happens.
when I press the 'btnJump' Button this event fires:

```
        private void btnJump_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabAddDocs.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

And here the tab is really showing.

What are the differences? 
How can i solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: No one will help you without a great deal more information. Try posting your xaml & code-behind.

Comment: Thanks, did that, please try to help me :)

Comment: put a breakpoint on empGrid_MouseDoubleClick. Is it ever hit?

Comment: Yes it is. my idea is that the datagrid takes the program's "attention" and  focus and from that wierd reason it's not functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suspect it is a focus/other behavior issue, try dispatching the selection to later:

```
private void btnJump_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {tabAddDocs.IsSelected = true;}, 
                           DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
}
```